# Database schema design to send unique messages to user

Tags: mysql, query

We are working on a system that users (hustler) can post their skills, and based on their listed skills, a client can try to hire them to assist them on a project. If a client enters specific text defining the skills sought, our system will search the database for matching text from skills posted by hustlers.

But apart from just producing results sets based on client search, we want to be able to send client posts to hustlers that match the criteria of skills a clients is looking for just like job sites find matching jobs for users.

So the question is, how can we send matching jobs requests to the hustler posted by clients without having to send duplicate records? I would like to know how this can be handled on the database level? One solution I thought of was to search on matching skill set AND also date posted e.g., if we have to send daily matching posts to a hustler, then we have to search matching skills AND created_date <= DATE_SUB(CurrentTime(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR). Something like this.

So please advise on how to best go about implementing this, and giving an example of a data model to handle this feature.

Comment: *how this can be handled on the database level?* As `SELECT DISTINCT hustler.email ...`.

Comment: But this query will be run everyday, so that command can send the same email that it has sent the previous day and other days. They records selected today might be distinct, but they are not distinct from previous records. In the case of online job search sites, you do not want to keep sending the same job matches to a candidate that you have sent to them before, but only new matching jobs. Hope this brings more clarity.

Comment: If so you must store somewhere the information which requests were already sent to a client. It can be simple list of sent request IDs (needs a separate table), or a timestamp of last dispatch which means that all requests with more ancient timestamps were already sent (needs additional field in client table).